# How to change pointer? copy constructor

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, copy

I want to make "set" function.                                                                    This function changes the values of a2 from "set(int x, int y)" to "y"

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class IntArray {
private:
    int* m_data;
    int m_len;
public:
    IntArray(int = 0, int = 0);
    ~IntArray();
    void print(void);
    IntArray(const IntArray& copy); // copy Constructor
    void set(int x , int y) {
        int temp = x;

        x = y;
        y = temp;//!!
    }
};
IntArray::IntArray(int size, int init) {
    if (size <= 0) {
        m_data = nullptr; m_len = 0;
    }
    else {
        m_data = new int[size];
        m_len = size;
        for (int idx = 0; idx < m_len; ++idx)
            *(m_data + idx) = init;
    }
}
IntArray::~IntArray() {
    delete[]m_data;
}
void IntArray::print(void) {
    for (int idx = 0; idx < m_len; ++idx)
        cout << *(m_data + idx) << ' ';
    cout << std::endl;
}
int main() {
    cout << "a1: ";
    IntArray a1{ 10, 100 };
    a1.print();
    cout << "a2: ";
    IntArray a2{ a1 };// 10~100
    a2.set(3, 999);
    a2.set(9, 123);
    a2.print();
    return 0;
}
```

**Excepted**

> a1: 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
> a2: 100 100 100 999 100 100 100 100 100 123

Comment: Well first of all you need to learn about [the rules of three, five and zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). After you follow them, then it's just a matter of plain assignment, like `*this = IntArray a2{ x,y };`

Comment: " *This =" causes an error. Why?

Comment: Spelling? `This` is not the same as `this`. And you *must* implement a proper copy-assignment operator first!

Comment: "This" is a typo.I modified it to "this" accordingly.

Comment: Is there any other way?

Comment: Any other way to do what?

Comment: "*this =" does not resolve the error. How else should I modify it to get the result I want?

Comment: Review comments 1 and 3 for the solution. You absolutely must read and understand the link in comment 1 to write effective and efficient C++ code. If you do not understand the rules of three, five, and zero, search Stack overflow explicitly for each of them. They are very well explained. If you still do not understand, ask questions about them.

Comment: So I add copy constructor "IntArray(const IntArray& copy);"

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need.

let's fix up your declaration and introduce two new helper methods, `alloc` and `copyFromOther`.

```
class IntArray {
private:
    int* m_data;
    int m_len;
    void alloc(int len);
    void copyFromOther(const IntArray& copy);
public:
    IntArray();
    IntArray(const IntArray& copy);
    ~IntArray();

    IntArray& operator=(const IntArray& copy);

    void print();
    void set(int index, int value);

};
```

Then the helper methods are for quick allocations and copy. Notice that I didn't special case `length == 0`. That's because it's perfectly fine to say, `new int[0]`. It will allocate a pointer of zero length. You can change this if you want to force a null pointer when length is zero. Also be aware that copy constructors need to be able to handle "copying to yourself".  That is, if you say:

```
IntArray arr(10, 20);
arr.set(5,5);
arr = arr;
```

As weird as the above looks, it's the source of a lot of bugs when a copy constructor doesn't handle that case.  That's covered below.

So now the implementation

```
void IntArray::alloc(int len) {
    delete [] m_data; // erase what we had before
    m_data = new int[len]; // you could say m_data = len ? new int[len] : nullptr
    m_len = len;
}

void IntArray::copyFromOther(const IntArray& copy) {

    // special case - allow for "copying to ourselves" by doing nothing
    // if we didn't handle this, the alloc function would delete the pointer
    if (copy.m_data == m_data) {
       return;
    }

    alloc(copy.m_len);
    for (int idx = 0; idx < m_len; ++idx)
        m_data[idx] = copy.m_data[idx];
    }
}
```

Then the implementation

```
IntArray::IntArray() : m_data(nullptr) {
   alloc(0);
}

IntArray::IntArray(const IntArray& copy) m_data(nullptr), m_len(0) {
   copyFromOther(copy);
}

IntArray& IntArray::operator=(const IntArray& copy) {
    copyFromOther(copy);
    return *this;
}
```

And let's fix your `set` method as you had asked about it in a separate question:

```
void IntArray::set(int index, int value) {
   if ((index >= 0) && (index < m_len)) {
       m_data[index] = value;
   }
}
```

Your destructor and print methods are fine as you have them. `print` doesn't need to have an explicit `void` parameter.